# How to specify port of MySQL in Drupal?

Tags: mysql, drupal, port

I need to change the default port of MySQL from 3306 to something else (let us say 3300)
I have edited setting.php in **sites/default.settings.php** and changed
**$db_url['default'] = 'mysqli://root:password@localhost/dbname';** TO
**$db_url['default'] = 'mysqli://root:password@localhost:3300/dbname';**
but this didn't work!
How can I change the default port?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing the cache? Drupal won't recognize the change if its pulling the data from elsewhere.

I think you can do it at yoursite.com/admin/settings/performance

Answer (score 0):

`$db_url['default'] = 'mysqli://root:password@localhost:3300/dbname';` should work. At least it does here, in several projects. You might have another bug.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also reconfigured your mysql server to work with the 3300 port?

Comment: sure i did, in fact i am searching for my bug!!! because i am sure my way of changing it in settings.php is correct 100%. however, even if i didnt change the port in my.cnf, at least the website shall not return anything after changing port in settings.php!! am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're editing the correct file. Either sites/default/settings.php or sites/mysite.com/settings.php. You shouldn't be editing the 'default.settings.php' file at all. It's a little unclear from your question if you might be.

Answer (score 0):

*MySQL* client library uses socket connection when using `localhost`, thus ignoring the port parameter and using the default setting.

In order to fix this you should use `127.0.0.1` instead of "localhost"

change

```
$db_url['default'] = 'mysqli://root:password@localhost:3300/dbname';
```

to

```
$db_url['default'] = 'mysqli://root:password@127.0.0.1:3300/dbname';
```

(Ressurecting this in case someone else stumbles on this issue)